# Count number of comments in articles

Tags: php, mysql

Please I want to add another table (Comments) to this query to count the number of comments for each article.

```
$query  = "SELECT M.id,M.j_surname,A.j_user_id,A.id,A.jart_title, A.jart_description, A.jart_createddate, COUNT(C.artid) AS count_comments FROM jt_articles A, jt_members M, jt_article_comments C where M.id = A.j_user_id AND C.artid = A.id ORDER BY A.jart_createddate DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update:
something like that (you dont post the scheme of the comments table)

```
      SELECT M.id,M.j_surname,A.j_user_id,A.id,A.jart_title, A.jart_description,
     A.jart_createddate , COUNT(A.id) AS count_comments
        FROM jt_articles A
left join  jt_members M on M.id = A.j_user_id 
left join  jt_article_comments C on C.artid = A.id        
        group by A.id
        ORDER BY A.jart_createddate DESC
```

Comment: This is what I have eventually and it is showing only one record with 4 comments. It is not working right. Can somebody help?                           $query  = "SELECT M.id,M.j_surname,A.j_user_id,A.id,A.jart_title, A.jart_description, A.jart_createddate, COUNT(C.artid) AS count_comments FROM jt_articles A, jt_members M, jt_article_comments C where M.id = A.j_user_id AND C.artid = A.id ORDER BY A.jart_createddate DESC

Comment: Worked but it shows only articles with comment. I also want it to show articles without comments(0).

Comment: Thank you but ALL the articles now are showing Comments(1) instead of correctly showing the no of comments.

Comment: last try change COUNT(A.id) to COUNT(C.artid)